# angular routing would not trigger a get request to the templateUrl

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i'm building a web app with angular, node, express. when i use  angular-routing it wont trigger a GET request to the `templateUrl`.

```
angular.module('chat',['ngRoute']);
angular.module('chat')
  .config(['$routeProvider',function($routeProvider){
        $routeProvider.when('/users',{
            templateUrl:'/templates/users.html'
        })
    }]);
```

when i use the `http://localhost/users` URL it sends back a 404 err.
but i know it isn't firing the get request to `/templates/users.html` because if i provide the full URL `http://localhost/templates/users.html` i get the template page displayed. How should i set it up to work that when i use `http://localhost/users` URL it will fetch the template and use it in `ng-view`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use relative-path in templateUrl. If your app.js where the routes are written should refer to the .html template relatively like :
if your app's file structure like this :

```
-app.js , index.html
-templates/users.html
```

then `templateUrl:'templates/users.html'`

To request this route you should request localhost/#/users , also specify the controller for this route using the 'controller'

Comment: didn't work. it is still firing the get request to http://localhost/users instead of the templateUrl path.

Comment: you should request localhost/#/users